# Use React children with another name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to set a name for `children` in react for better code readability?
I want something like this:

```
default function LinksBar({ links = children }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {links} {/* instead of {children} */}
        </div>
    )
};
```

I know I can pass them in props, but I don't want to do it this way (just because of personal preference).

### I don't want this:

```
<LinksBar links={<><Link href="1" /><Link href="2" /><>} />
```

### I want this:

```
<LinksBar>
    <Link href="1" />
    <Link href="2" />
<LinksBar/>
```

Comment: This is useful. I couldn't find a list of "special" variable names used in React. Being able to rename or "aliasing" them for something that makes more sense in my code is nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function LinksBar({ links = children })` defines a parameter destructuring default, not destructuring renaming; it expects a `links` property and, if it's not found or has the value `undefined`, tries to default it to a `children` in-scope variable (presumably failing because there isn't one).

For renaming destructuring syntax, you want `{children: links}` instead:

```
default function LinksBar({children: links}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {links}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I go into destructuring in some detail in Chapter 7 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

You can alias it, although React speaking, it's less readable, in my opinion:

`function LinksBar({ children: links })`